# gitlab-ci file for an angular 6 project

Tags: angular, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm using angular 6 for my project. 
This is my .gitignore file content:

```
# See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.
# compiled output
/dist
/tmp
/out-tsc

# dependencies
/node_modules

# IDEs and editors
/.idea
.project
.classpath
.c9/
*.launch
.settings/
*.sublime-workspace

# IDE - VSCode
.vscode/*
!.vscode/settings.json
!.vscode/tasks.json
!.vscode/launch.json
!.vscode/extensions.json

# misc
/.sass-cache
/connect.lock
/coverage
/libpeerconnection.log
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
testem.log
/typings

# System Files
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
```

Since the node_modules folder is not pushed into the git, how can I configure the gitlab-ci file for an automatic deployment?

Answer (score 0):

If you install node packages with the following command:

```
npm install
```

Then you can use the same command in your build scripts:

```
my_job:
  before_script:
    - npm install
  script:
    - my_script
```

If your job is executed on a runner that has access to Internet and that has npm installed, this should work. Depending on how your deploy process works, you can either upload `artifacts` in GitLab, or call some other script that does this for you.

You can also use a cache in GitLab to reuse the node_modules folder between builds, [example from here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#caching-nodejs-dependencies):

```
image: node:latest

# Cache modules in between jobs
cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
  - node_modules/

before_script:
  - npm install

test_async:
  script:
  - node ./specs/start.js ./specs/async.spec.js
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. yes I used npm install for starting but I added new unmatched modules to a new project